Drools as a library in Spring Boot
I'm working on a relatively small project for my company where I need to implement a rule engine using Drools and expose it through an API built with Spring Boot. We plan to deploy the application internally using Kubernetes. Since I'm new to Drools, I have a few questions regarding the best approach:
I would use Drools version 8.44.Final because it's the newest. I'm completely new to Drools and was wondering what the smartest path is. My idea was using Drools as a library, not using Kogito or KieServer. Is this smart and is it even possible? If I use it only as a library and add dependencies in my pom.xml, should I use the old way with KieServices to get a KieSession and insert rules or should I use the new way of Rule Units?
I read through the documentation, set up a beginner project, but when I added Drools dependencies in pom.xml and set up a Spring config class for KieContainer and KieSession, there were a lot of problems. I expected to use these for executing rules but need advice on best practices for Drools 8.44.Final.

It's totally possible. I've used Drools for 12+ years now and I've never used Kogito or whatever. Here's a simple Drools + Spring Boot app I wrote for some article I was writing, that you can use as an example since "a lot of problems" is kind of vague: https://github.com/roddy/library-demo

Your question as written is too broad though. "Should I" is an opinion question that you need to evaluate for yourself based on your requirements. The Drools documentation is excellent and has been that way for many years -- so even the older 7.xx documentation is still fantastic. I recommend starting there and looking at how it suggests doing things given your requirements and use cases.
